# LabVIEW: How to share a .NET object created from LabVIEW

Tags: labview

I have a class called Camera in the .NET library and once I instantiate the object I want to create a reference of it so that this instance can be used from other VIs. How do I make a reference or how do I make it global ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple ways to approach your question.

Possible answer 1: You're looking to let multiple parallel subVIs use the object at the same time. The .NET wire is already a reference wire. Forking that wire does not copy the object. Just wire it into the other VIs, however many there are, and let them all use the reference.

Possible answer 2: You're trying to obtain the existing reference in another VI without passing the reference on a wire through a subVI conpane or Call By Reference node. In this case, you would pass the .NET object refnum the same way you would pass any other bit of data in LabVIEW when avoiding wires. **In general, the rule is "avoid passing data outside of dataflow."** Seriously... try to pass the refnum through a conpane... if this program is going to have any significant lifetime, you'll be happier when you can take that approach. **BUT... when such outside-of-dataflow passing is necessary,** there are many tools -- queues, notifiers, global VIs, data value references, functional globals. Which of those tools is the right one depends greatly on what you're actually trying to achieve. The simplest is to create a global VI, but that introduces a lot of polling checks as the second VI has to keep polling the global to see if the first VI has stored the value yet or not. A notifier refnum is probably the most flexible option that I can point you toward... create a named notifier of your .NET refnum type. Both first and second VI can obtain the notifier by name. The second VI then blocks on Wait For Notificiation waiting for the first VI to write the refnum into the notifier. See http://zone.ni.com/reference/en-XX/help/371361L-01/glang/create_notifier/ for more information on notifiers. Or Google the other terms that I listed if that seems insufficient for your needs.